# bind9, named not accessible over local network behind router ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

i have a zte F6600R router from my isp provider with following configuration

```
DHCP SERVER : ON
LAN IP ADDR : 192.168.1.1
SUBNET MASK : 255.255.255.0
DHCP start IP : 192.168.1.10
DHCP end IP : 192.168.1.250
ISP DNS : OFF
PRIMARY DNS : 8.8.8.8 // working internet fine
SECONDARY DNS: 8.8.4.4 // working internet fine
LEASE TIME MODE: CUSTOM
CUSTOM LEASE TIME : 86400
```

following bind configuration:

> named.conf

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
//include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

following

> named.conf.local

```
zone "webtrade.dark" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/forward.webtrade.dark";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/reverse.webtrade.dark";
};
```

following

> named.conf.options

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    listen-on { any; };
    allow-query { any; };
    forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
    
    dnssec-validation auto;
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

following

> forward.webtrade.dark

```
$TTL    14400
@   IN  SOA blastwave.webtrade.dark. root.blastwave.webtrade.dark. (
                  7     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  blastwave.webtrade.dark.
blastwave   IN  A   192.168.1.12
www IN  A   192.168.1.12
@   IN  AAAA    ::1
```

following

> reverse.webtrade.dark

```
$TTL    14400
@   IN  SOA blastwave.webtrade.dark. root.blastwave.webtrade.dark. (
                  7     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  blastwave.webtrade.dark.
blastwave   IN  A   192.168.1.12
12  IN  PTR blastwave.webtrade.dark.
```

in named status all works fine zones loaded dig ok with authority over webtrade.dark, dig on reverse with 1 answer and 0 authority

following

> /etc/resolv.conf

```
search webtrade.dark
nameserver 192.168.1.12
```

following

> /etc/default/named

```
RESOLVCONF=no
OPTIONS="-u bind -4"
```

> hostname --fqdn => blastwave

haven't touched */etc/hosts* file

> installed apache2 on the dns server machine

the defined domain is not accessible by the other devices on the network pc phone etc.
what do i miss? please help

> UPDATE
> [image: named status]

```
netstat -pnltu | grep ':53'
```

[image: status pid ip port]

Comment: Is the DNS listening to IPV4 on your local network? Does `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` need `listen-on { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.12; };` ?

Comment: yes, no result :(. I changed it to "any"

Comment: What do you mean by "is not accessible"? It cannot be pinged? It doesn't repond to dig? It doesn't recurse? Please show an actual command that fails, and the error that you see. Also what is the role of that router in the title of your question? How do you mean _behind_ router? Is any network relevant other than your local `192.168.1/24`?

Comment: on the server machine everything works fine with pinging digging nslookup on the webtrade.dark, i can't access it from my ex pc on the local network. When i try pinging from my pc could not find host webtrade.dark though server's ip is accessible, pingable, nslookupable - defined domain NOT instead

Comment: edit nslookup on pc returns server unknown